# if variable == 'String' : doSomething()?

Tags: python, dictionary, if-statement

I compare each element of the list `['a','c']` in an if-statement control flow with a string like this:

```
charlist = ['a','b']

for el in charlist:
    if el is'a' or 'A':
        print('a is done')
    if el is 'b' or 'B':
        print('b is done')
    if el is 'c' or 'C':
        print('why c?')
```

**Output is:**

 a is done

b is done

why c?

> why does this execute the "if el is 'c' or 'C':" statement?
>   
> I think only the first two are executed?

**But this solution worked for me**

```
for el in charlist:
    if el == 'a' or el == 'A':
       print('a is done')
    if el == 'b' or el == 'B':
       print('b is done')
    if el == 'c' or el == 'C':
       print('c is done')
```

Comment: `el is 'c' or 'C'`: ->  `el == 'c' or el=='C'`

Comment: @EliKorvigo They are ifs, not elifs.

Comment: it worked for me @mad_, thx

Comment: @dfundako True enough, I've already removed my comment. The pattern-matcher in my visual cortex mistook  `if el` for `elif`.

Comment: You might also take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52851057/not-sure-why-my-if-and-else-statements-are-not-working-in-python#comment92617822_52851057), because it is an exact duplicate of your question and the comments show better solutions than the one you've picked.

Answer (score -1):

Try doing it this way for clarity:

```
charlist = ['a','b']

for el in charlist:
  if el =='a' or el =='A':
     print('a is done')
  if el == 'b' or el =='B':
     print('b is done')
  if el == 'c' or el == 'C':
      print('why c?')
```